# Questions about lambda and eval in relation to some Python calculator GUI code

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

To start here's some of the code;

```
    from Tkinter import*


def button (source, side, text, command = None) :
    storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

        EqualsButton = Calculator(self, TOP)
        for Equals in '=':
            if Equals == '=':
                btnEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, Equals)
                btnEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                               lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
            else:
                btnEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, Equals,
                                   lambda storeObj=display, s=' %s ' %Equals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))

    def calc(self, display):
        try:
            display.set(eval(display.get()))
        except:
            display.set("ERROR")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```

I understand most of the first few blocks, functions that I can call later to build the calculator (ie the buttons and the frame). Things I don't understand nor is there an explanation for are syntax such as storeObj, and storeObj.pack. I also don't fully understand where the actual calculation is performed, I would assume it be in the EqualsButton block, specifically the two lambda statements, I can't wrap my head around what the lambda are actually doing though, even though I'm familiar with plenty of the syntax. I coded a calculator in C and it was fairly intuitive but when it comes to this python code I don't know what I'm looking at, or what I should be looking for. Would be nice if someone gave a quick rundown. New to programming so excuse the pea brain.

Edit: Cut some code that wasn't relevant. Got some great answers already thanks. I can PM the full program for anyone that wants it.

Comment: We are not mentors, we don't teach people how to read and/or understand code. We only help with specific issues with said code (a.k.a "my code does this, but I expect it to do that. I tried such and such stuff to make it do what I want, but I didn't succeed, so I'm asking you to help"). If you don't understand what the code does, you should ask for help elsewhere.

Comment: @ForceBru Although the title might seem very broad I do understand plenty of the code. I have specified what I don't understand, ie where the calculation takes place, storeObj syntax, and the lambda statements. There's many threads similar to this asking for a line by line explanation and getting very informative and useful responses, I'm asking for but a quarter of this, not sure what the problem is!

Comment: 1) there's nothing special about "storeObj syntax". `storeObj` is just a variable. What's the problem here? 2) explaining `lambda` syntax and the usage of `lambda` functions is described in the docs. 3) It's not hard to see that the calculation takes place in the function called `calc`. `calc`ulation.

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you for somewhat of an answer! I assumed storeObj was syntax specific to tkinter and not just simply a variable, in hindsight that was dumb, but as I said I'm very new to programming so. As far as lambda I was hoping for someone to take one specific lambda statement eg ' lambda storeObj=display, s=' %s ' %Equals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))' and explain in layman terms what's actually happening, I'll swat up on lambda stuff see if I can make any sense of it.

Comment: @ForceBru Also as far as the calculation goes, my assumption was based on the fact that the answer appears after the user releases the equals button, which drew me to that block, again I was wrong unsurprisingly. Your reply appears a tad biting, hopefully I'm just reading too much into it, just a newbie looking for answers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigned variables are just that. Assigned by the coder. I have variable_name = object. If there are Tkinter specific variables being used at some point it is most likely a PSEUDO-CONSTANT that is used in arguments within the methods of tkinter. You should never try to change predefined variables that are part of the tkinter library.

The `pack()` portion is just placing the Frame object in the root window to be viewed by the user.

`pack()` is part of a set of geometry managers used to place objects on the GUI such as the frame or a text box or an entry field and many more. The details of `pack()` or any geometry manager are well documented in tkinter docs.

Lambda statements are also documented extensively but simply they anonymous functions. This means you do not need to assign this function a name. They are also one line functions. Their use is common in python and tkinter.

As for where the calculation is actually happening is the `eval` operation.
This is the code being used to perform the actual calculation.

```
def calc(self, display):
    try:
        display.set(eval(display.get()))
    except:
        display.set("ERROR")
```

This method specifically is what is performing the calculation:

```
eval(display.get())
```

As `eval` is not commonly know for newer programmers or ones new to python I can see how you were not sure where this might be calculated however the function name should be a clue as `calc` is short for `calculation` or `calculate`.

Comment: Everything makes much more sense now thanks a bunch.